# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties during migration from Net Core 3.1 to Net 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to migrate from .Net Core 3.1 to .Net 6. I updated TargetFramework and some dependencies.

And I have this piece of code

```
public CustomerSettingsDefaults(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection configuration)
{
  ....
  var personalizedUrls = configuration.GetRequiredSection(@"PersonalizedUrls");
```

However during project build it

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
> properties:
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationExtensions.GetRequiredSection(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration,
> string)' and
> 'Common.Extensions.ConfigurationExtensions.GetRequiredSection(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration,
> string)'  Crm.Infrastructure  C:...\Configuration\CustomerSettingsDefaults.cs    23  Active

My ConfigurationExtensions is defined like this

```
namespace Common.Extensions
{
    public static class ConfigurationExtensions
    {
        public static IConfigurationSection GetRequiredSection(this IConfiguration configuration, string sectionName)
        {
            var section = configuration.GetSection(sectionName);
            if (section is null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($@"The configuration is missing the {sectionName} section");
            }

            return section;
        }
    }
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Make sure you do a clean build.  When changing versions of Net the dependencies in the compiler doesn't automatically update all the libraries.

Comment: @jdweng No, the compiler definitely _will_ update everything (or, rather, use the new dependencies).

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's a conflict between your own `GetRequiredSection` extension method and the `GetRequiredSection` that was added to `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions` in .NET 6. Both extend the same interface and take the same parameters, so if both namespaces (your `Common.Extensions` and .NET's `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`) are in scope, of course the compiler doesn't know which one to pick.

So you could just delete your own extension method altogether, since it seems to do the same thing that the one provided by .NET does, and that means one less thing to maintain for you.

If you absolutely need to keep using your own method, then you need to call it explicitly  like a static method:

```
  var personalizedUrls = Common.Extensions.ConfigurationExtensions.GetRequiredSection(configuration, "PersonalizedUrls");
```

Comment: Where I can look at the  source code GetRequiredSection provided by  NET6? Just  to compare.

Comment: @lapots [It's here](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions/ConfigurationExtensions.cs,3fd7dd17c4df1de0). The main difference is that it uses a more elaborate method of checking if the value exists (not just if it's null, but also if it has no value and no children).

Answer (score 0):

'Call is ambiguous' error is always for those function calls for which there are 2 similar function in the code in which neither functions are either overloading or overriding the other function.
To get rid of the error and you want to call a specific function, either you can call out the whole function i.e.,
instead of calling
GetRequiredSection(), call
Common.Extensions.ConfigurationExtensions.GetRequiredSection()